# JavaFX - put columns id/order in a List/Array

Tags: java, javafx, get, tableview

How can I put the columns order / columns id in a Array or in a List.

I'm using JavaFX tableview...

with `list.getColumns();` I can get the columns from the tableview..

[image]

But how can I get the order in a list or array?

So that the list/array contains `//1,2,3,4,5,6` the column order

Comment: Do you want the columns in a sorted order?

Answer (score 1):

According to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getColumns()) this gives you the order the tableview currently has:

getColumns
--> 
public final ObservableList> getColumns()
The TableColumns that are part of this TableView. As the user reorders the TableView columns, this list will be updated to reflect the current visual ordering.

**Note:** to display any data in a TableView, there must be at least one TableColumn in this ObservableList.

Here you go for an answer:

```
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TableColumn<String, ?> col : table.getColumns()) columns.add(col.getText());
    System.out.println(columns.toString());
```

I used `TableView<String> table`you must adapt it to your type of TableView of course :)

Comment: this doesnt answerd my question .-.